# Soundfx library metadata language 

Tags: soundminer, sound-libraries, sfx, metadata

Dear all

I'll planning to sort some of the stuff in my sfx libraries. I'll move to Soundminer and thinking to tag and add metadata to all my libraries (I'll start, but I already know that it'll be a loooooong project).

I'm Italian so I'm thinking: should I tag and rename all my libraries (self recorded and bought) in italian (much easier to do and to work with) or should I do that in english (a little more difficult to do and to use but much more consistent with any new library that i could buy and much more usefull if I'll move outside italy for work)? 
What dou you french/spanish/whereverintheworldareyou do? :)

thanks in advance

davide

Comment: My instinct is to keep it in English if you ever think you will come to the US to sound design. You'll thank yourself later I think.

Answer (score 1):

Consider how much easier it will be to use Italian, now, vs. how hard it will be to translate all your new libraries, later.  Will you be purchasing a lot of libraries, or will you be relying mostly on stuff you'll be recording yourself?

It's just a matter of comparing headaches, and deciding which will be worse.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that Soundminer may have some caveats with Unicode characters, so I equally vouch for the English.  ProTools, Soundminer, and any intermediate software is natively written with English characters in mind so that may yield the best results for future cross-compatibility.